# Cannot run C++ CMake project in netbeans

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, cmake

I have a C++ project that is built using CMake. I want to build and run it in netbeans (8.2). I can import and build the project successfully, no problems there.

However, when I come to run it, I get a 'No executable specified in project' error. The popup invites me to navigate to the executable generated by CMake. When I navigate to the binary, it is not recognised by netbeans as an elf executable file. If I navigate to the file and do

```
file myExecutable
```

Linux reports it as ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64 etc...

I can run the executable from the command line so not problem there either.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for some reason the NetBeans 8.2 doesn't recognize the CMake-built executable files. One way to bypass this problem is:

- Open the `Project Properties` popup window.
- Click on `Run` button in the left pane to open run settings.
- The `Run Command` setting is used to be the `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"` string. Replace this string by your *relative* executable name `./myExecutable`.
- Click `OK` to save properties.

This should do the trick.

**UPDATE:** I've just found out that adding compiler option `-no-pie` (do not create a position independent executable) allows the NetBeans to find executables correctly (at least in Ubuntu 18.04) - in this case you won't need any changes in the project properties.